# User ranks: how to do it without SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, ranking

I am developing server-side part of an online game and one of the tasks is to compute user ranks. At the moment its done using RDBMS, but it updates each user row every time some player wins a game. It results in deadlocks now, when there are 20 players online on average.

I understand the tendency - when there would be 1000 players database solution won't work at all.

How to compute user ranks at real time at Apache/PHP server? It there smarter database solution?

Comment: Deadlocks at 20 users? Sounds like you're using Access. Y/N?

Comment: Not at all. I am using MySQL, but user ranks updates may overlap when multiple users accessing database simultaneously. Which causing deadlocks, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your ranks in another table, which you `TRUNCATE` each time.
A similar question has already been asked (and answered) and can be found here:
[Best way to update user rankings without killing the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948832/best-way-to-update-user-rankings-without-killing-the-server)

Comment: Great solution, thanks. But I am wondering, if there is a solution which doesn't use RDBMS at all? Task is solved easily using balanced BSTs, maybe there is something ready for Apache/PHP?

Comment: Implemented such an approch, but it now generates lots of duplicate key errors. The thing is that multiple users can run rank updation at the same time which would result in queries overlapping. Seems like the solution just transforms the problem into ahother one, but doesn't solve it.

Comment: What about Sammich' approach?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you store the ranks in a separate table at all? Store the scores and query for the ranks as needed, or even create a View. You only have to update data relevant to a single user, rather than updating the entire table, and if you're using InnoDB tables the UPDATE queries will use row-level locking rather than table-level locking you get with myISAM.

```sql
TABLE users
  user_id INT PK
  user_name VARCHAR
  ...

TABLE user_scores
  user_id PK FK
  score INT INDEX
  wins INT INDEX

VIEW v_user_ranks
  SELECT u.user_id, u.user_name, s.score, s.wins
  FROM users u INNER JOIN user_scores s
    ON u.user_id = s.user_id

SELECT *
FROM v_user_ranks
ORDER BY score, wins DESC
LIMIT 10

INSERT INTO user_scores (user_id, score, wins)
  VALUES ($id, $score, $wins)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score=score+$score, wins=wins+$wins
```

Comment: The thing is that I need to be able to retrieve user rank quite fast (to tell user their old/new rank and change when they win a game) and also be able to show user rating table sorted not by rank, but by some other category (by alphabet, for ex.). That is why I need to actualize user ranks each time they may change.

Comment: Your way involves updating an *entire table* each time a user wins a game, then selecting X rows ordered in a particular way. My way involves updating a *single row*, then selecting X rows in a particular order. Which one sounds faster? Also, when performing operations that involve the entire table so often you're never going to get around the table-level deadlocks you're fighting with right now.

Comment: Haven't understood your way yet, sorry( Could u elaborate it more for me, please. What is score and what is wins? Where is user rank?

Comment: @user1065145 the `score` and `wins` fields would store the cumulative score and number of wins for the player, and the ranking would be determined from the row index in the result set. There *are* ways to force in an actual number in the result set, but it's easier and more flexible to do in the program code rather than the query.

Comment: Thats is ok, when you only need to get rank of a single player at a time. What if you need all of them simultaneously?

Comment: @user1065145 with a SELECT statement. Like the one in my answer. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: What if I need rating table sorted by username, but also with ranks? I.e. ABC - 32nd place, EEE - 234th place, XYZ - 1st place, ZZZ - 45st place, etc.